# Line Break in Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm using QRBot Business Scanner Mode, and I have the following API provided by the author, this runs on windows:

```
import cherrypy
scans = []
class Scans:
    exposed = True
    def GET(self):
        return ('\n').join(scans)
    def POST(self, content):
        scans.append(content)
        return ('Append new scan with content: %s' % content)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        'global': {
           'server.socket_host': '192.168.1.111',
           'server.socket_port': 8080,
        },
        '/': {
           'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        },
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(Scans(), '/scans/', conf)
```

And I get the following output in browser:

```
9501101530003 0671860013624 09501101530003 9771234567003
```

I want to format the output like:

```
9501101530003
0671860013624
09501101530003
9771234567003
```

Can you please help me? This will be gladly accepted. Thank You!

Comment: Did you try adding `<br>` tags?

Comment: `'\n'.join()` will add `\n` character  not line break after each element

Comment: The App won't allow me to put <> in the HTTP Body section. It only let me put 'content=[code]' See: http://qrbot.net/business-scanner-mode-howto/

Answer (score 0):

You want to set response headers to `text/plain`.

```
class Scans:
    exposed = True
    def GET(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        return ('\n').join(scans)
```

That will make the newlines display as actual newlines, instead of the browser trying to render them as HTML.

Comment: Worked beautifully, Thanks!! Just a quick question, since I'm pasting the results in excel, how do I add an ' to the start of the barcode?

Comment: `"'" + "\n'".join(scans)`

Comment: Thank you! I'm using: return ("\n"+"'").join(scans) just to add one ' at the beggining of every barcode but the very first code doesn't show with the '

Comment: That's why I said `"'" + "\n'".join(scans)`. Re-read the line. You're adding `'` to the beginning of the resultant str.